Delimit string to search in SQL
Wondering if there is a way to delimit string to search in sql. I primarily use notepad++ to delimit string, but is there a way to accomplish this in SQL? In this example, I delimit the string with (',') in notepad++ which I can then place in a sql query.
Example via Notepad ++:
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
EEEE

Delimited string via notepad++:
AAAA','BBBB','CCCC','DDDD','EEEE

SQL query
SELECT ID
FROM test.dbo.testtable
WHERE id in ('AAAA','BBBB','CCCC','DDDD','EEEE')


Please specify the version of SQL server.

This one works in MySql 8 but I think it has room for performance improvement.
The result of * from split_string are



part




AAAA


BBBB


CCCC


DDDD


EEEE



set @originalString = 'AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE';

SELECT ID FROM test.dbo.testtable WHERE id in
(WITH RECURSIVE split_string AS (
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(@originalString, ' ', 1) AS part,
        SUBSTRING(
            @originalString,
            LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@originalString, ' ', 1)) + 2
        ) AS rest
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(rest, ' ', 1),
        SUBSTRING(rest, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(rest, ' ', 1)) + 2)
    FROM
        split_string
    WHERE
        rest <> ''
) SELECT part FROM split_string);


I would assume OP is using MS SQL Server (due to the  tag.)

The most straightforward way of generating your CSV IN clause might be the following replacement:
Find:    (\S+)
Replace: '$1',

Note that this would generate the following:
input:  AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE
output: 'AAAA','BBBB','CCCC','DDDD','EEEE',

You would then have to manually trim away the final dangling comma to get what you want.
